# Uploading picture files to main domain from page on the subdomain

Tags: php, file-upload, server, ftp

I am creating a subdomain for my main site, example.com, which has user accounts with profile pictures. Both the sub and the main site use the same DB. Before creating the sub, all profile pics were stored on a directory named "users" on the main site.

Calling the photos from this folder is not a problem. But I would like the user to have the ability to change their profile pic while navigating the subdomain. As it is, the current script will allow the upload, but it puts it in the "users" directory of the subdomain, not the main site.

What is the best way to create a path to the "users" directory on the main site?

The directory paths are currently set up on the server like so...

> Main -> /example.com/public_html/users
>
> Sub -> /sub.example.com/public_html/users

I have tried "../../example.com/public_html/users", but that did not work.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Create a [SYMBOLIC LINK](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.symlink.php) --  This allows the directory to be used in two locations.  IE `/var/www/main/users -> /var/www/sub/users`

Comment: @Zak, thank you for the suggestion. Your suggestion helped me realize that I wasn't going up the tree far enough. I used "../../../www/example.com/public_html/" as my relative path did not incorporate the www directory. If you want to officially answer my question, I'll give you credit for the helpful answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can effectively have the directory in two places if you use a [SYMBOLIC LINK](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.symlink.php)

This would allow you to use `example.com/public_html/users` AND `/sub.example.com/public_html/users` simultaneously.

Syntax is simple:

```
$target = '/example.com/public_html/users';
$link = '/sub.example.com/public_html/users';
symlink($target, $link);
```